# Eclipse SDK Upgrade To 3.7 Conflict Dependency

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to upgrade my Eclipse SDK form Version 3.6.1 to 3.7.2 but I am getting the following error after including http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo under the add software sites and then going to Help>Check New Updates:-

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Eclipse SDK 3.7.2.M20120208-0800 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.7.2.M20120208-0800)

What do I need to do to complete the upgrade?

Comment: Don't upgrade at all.  Go to eclipse.org, get the 3.7 version, and unzip it to a different directory than your 3.6 version.

Comment: That's one way. You should have another error line dictating what the dependency conflict might be related to. It's possible that you have a newer version of a dependent and it will not go down in version number and fails.

Comment: @apesa Unfortunately there is no other line indicated in the error message.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's a fine idea actually. But I was wondering if there was any way of permanently removing Eclipse including from the registries as well?

Comment: Post your error message. The offending library is in the message I have fixed this type of error several times. Your library base is out of sync. Otherwise as @Gilbert suggested move to another release. Since Eclipse is java based you don't need registry entries it just needs a classpath. Go to regedit and search for Eclipse. I will say moving to another release sucks if you have configured the one your in for your specific work.